# Networkx degree centrality

Tags: python, networking, analysis

I found the degree centrality for all my nodes but they are all below 1. I am looking at the connected component of an undirected graph.

```
bcGC_dict = dict(nx.betweenness_centrality(GC))
ordered_bcGC = sorted(bcGC_dict, key = bcGC_dict.get,reverse = True)

print("\n top 11 betweenness centrality connected component:")


for i in range(11):
    print(ordered_bcGC[i])
```

and the output for the node with the highest degree centrality is :

> 0.6933097652302072

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it possible to have a betweenness centrality below 1? I can't see how it can be. I don't really know if this is the right place for this but please help if you can. I really appreciate it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the NetworkX function [`degree_centrality`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.degree_centrality.html) you can read:

> The degree centrality values are normalized by dividing by the maximum possible degree in a simple graph n-1 where n is the number of nodes in G.

However if you need to calculate the connected component there is a function right for that called `connected_components`. Also you can check for similar methods [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/algorithms.component.html).